# how to change the cssclass of a div after press a button in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I am trying to change the background of a div after clicking a button. this are the codes.
Div I want to change color:

```
 <div id="example1" runat="server">

 </div>
```

and CSS for it:

```
#example1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    top:0;
    background-color: orange;
    width: 310px;
    height: 34px;
    color: white;

    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

I want to change it to this:

```
#example2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    top:0;
    background-color: red;
    width: 380px;
    height: 38px;
    color: white;

    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

I tried to write some code at Page.aspx.cs

```
example1.CssClass = "example2";
```

but looks like CssClass is not a function of the div. how can I add it? or whats a way to do it on C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to go back to server, in order to change the color of your div. This can be done solely on client by writing a simple script:

```js
var example1 = document.getElementById("example1");

example1.addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.className = "example2";
});
```

```css
.example2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    top:0;
    background-color: red;
    width: 380px;
    height: 38px;
    color: white;

    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="example1" runat="server">
  sample text
</div>
```

**Important Note**

In your case, since your div is a server side control, (`runat="server"`), the id that is generated before the page is sent to the client is not `example1`. So in the script I presented above we have to make a change:

```
var example1 = document.getElementById("<%= example1.ClientID%>");
```

Comment: runat=sever was just to call the div in the page.aspx.cs is not important for the code. can be removed without a problem. thats javascript?

Comment: @AltjenB. If you don't need it, then the snippet's code does exactly that you want. The snippet does this with plain JavaScript.

Comment: Hey @Christos. can you update the code with an other function? I mean. when I press button1. and textbox1 and textbox2 are wrong it will turn red (or go to the example2 css class) and after textbox1 is clicked it will change to example1

Comment: the code you gave me changes the class when I press the textbox. but not the button. and I am not understanding how to give the button1 function click to do the click

Comment: Don't forget that IDs are more specific than classes so you may have a specificity issue with this solution.  I would just give the default a class of `example1` and only style the classes...leave IDs out of it.

Answer (score 0):

For this answer, I will assume based on your code that you will be handling the click event on the back end.

The issue is your CSS is targeting the elements by id but you are trying to assign a CSS class by name.

First, change your div to use the class by name:

```
<div id="example1" class="example1" runat="server">

</div>
```

(The name of the class is your choice. I just used the same for simplicity)

Then change your CSS classes to NOT target an id:

```
.example2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    top:0;
    background-color: red;
    width: 380px;
    height: 38px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Notice the period (.) instead of the hash (#).